# How to router PHP error log to CloudWatch

Tags: php, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I forward all php warnings and errors that typically go to the errror_log file , to go to CloudWatch ( preferably, also know which instance generated each warning)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use or switch to using Monolog, then here is a connector you can use for Monolog and CloudWatch Logs: [AWS CloudWatch Logs Handler for Monolog](https://github.com/maxbanton/cwh)